# Can't pass args through to rake task - has the syntax changed?

Tags: ruby, rake

I'm using a rails 3.1.3 project which has rake (0.9.2.2).  I want to do this in a rake task: call it like

```
rake tale:import_kml /path/to/file.txt
```

and then inside the rake task, get access to "/path/to/file.txt" as args.filename

I thought i would be able to do this like so (the puts is there for bit of debugging):

```
namespace :tale do
  desc "Expects to get a file or folder name as the first argument, and passes that to Tale.import_kml"
  task(:import_kml, [:filename] => :environment) do |t, args|
    puts "args = #{args.inspect}"
    if File.exists?(args.filename)
      Tale.import_kml(filename)
    end
  end
end
```

But, i get this:

```
** Invoke tale:import_kml (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute tale:import_kml
args = {}
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String
```

so, filename isn't making it into args.  I can't work out what i'm doing wrong here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try such snippet:

```
namespace :tale do
  desc "Expects to get a file or folder ..."
  task(:import_kml, [:filename]) do |t, args|
    args.with_default(:filename => :environment)
    puts "args = #{args.inspect}"
  end
end

rake tale:import_kml[foo]  # => args = {:filename => "foo"}
```

Comment: That works!  thanks :)  Still not sure why my attempt didn't though.  btw in your code snippet you call `tale:important_kml[foo]` instead of `tale:import_kml[foo]`, just mentioning this in case anyone else gets confused by it :)

Comment: Actually WarHog that hasn't fixed it because i don't have access to my rails env inside the rake task, and so can't call `Tale.import_kml(filename)` (Tale is one of my AR models)

Answer (score 0):

WarHog helped me work it out:  i had to change the 'task' line to

```
task :import_kml, [:filename] => [:environment] do |t, args|
```

and call it like

```
rake tale:import_kml[/path/to/file.txt]
```